# Disabled button which is not embedded in the post

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, onclick

> This is an editted question. Apologised for not stating it clearly.

I've a news page which will display list of product and a button accessible for user to click to take a look at the coupon available. I unsure on how to get it done.

```
 <button id="coupon_id" type="submit" value="Coupon" class="buttonlink"
                                onclick="parent.location='<?php echo 'receipt-singleview?id=' . $eachData["couponId"]; ?>'">Coupon</button>
```

i tried to code this but it was halfway cause i just testing it out.

```
<script>
        if(!$('input').val()){
    $('#coupon_id').hide();
}
else {
    $('#coupon_id').show();
}
</script>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/V4u5X/867/

Comment: forgive me for that. @bhargavponnapalli

Comment: Jquery within a PHP block? It should be <script> if()... </script> instead of <?php ?>.

Comment: oh yes. but i'm unsure on how  to go about it. I assume that what i've coded is actually halfway done. @bhargavponnapalli

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you can use the $().html method to set the arrow that you want.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x8oebpqf/

```
    if($this.hasClass('SeeMore2')){
        $this.html('&#9654');           
    } else {
        $this.html('&#9660');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? 
https://jsfiddle.net/svq5scnm/

```js
$('.SeeMore2').click(function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.toggleClass('SeeMore2');
        $this.toggleClass('SeeLess2');
  
 });
```

```css
.SeeMore2 .less{
    display:none;
}
.SeeLess2 .more{
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="SeeMore2"><span class="more">See More <span class="arrowdown">&#x25BA;</span></span><span class="less">See Less <span class="arrowup">&#x25B2;</span></span></button>
```

Comment: Hi, i would like to ask. How to disabled/hide a button if a coupon page does not have a default coupon which it is not embedded with the post? @bhargavponnapalli